# Fragment replace makes root layout visible. How to fix?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am experiencing the following issue:
I have a single activity and a fragment container inside this activity layout. After user presses a button from the single activity root layout I call:

```
 supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.custom_fade_in, R.anim.custom_fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.single_activity_container, firstFragment, FIRST_FRAGMENT)
            .commitNow()
```

It works well. However, if I need to add another fragment on top of existing I use same code block. The issue is that **previous fragment gets removed** and user can see root view **for a split second**. This is really a bad UX and I found no way to solve it. I need smooth transition, without revealing root layout again.

I specificcally need to **use replace** in order to trigger Fragments onPause and onResume, because calling add(), **does not trigger lifecycle events**.

How should I structure my presentation logic to fix this UX issue?

Comment: Why not delay the fade-out animation so that there is no moment when both fragments are exactly `50%/50%` alpha?

Comment: Good idea, any sample on how to do that? :)

my fade in:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.6" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="300"/>

and fade out:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.4" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="300"/>